# SQL Server: avg rate for male and female employees in AdventureWorks

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, adventureworks

I'm trying to write a query to find the average pay rate for male and female employees in the AdventureWorks database

I wrote this (below), but I am not getting the desired results:

```
with sub as 
(
   select 
       emp.Gender, emp.VacationHours, pay.Rate
   from 
       HumanResources.Employee emp, HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory pay
   where 
       emp.BusinessEntityID = pay.BusinessEntityID
)
select 
    sub.Gender,
    avg(sub.VacationHours) as vac_hours, 
    avg(sub.Rate) as rate
from 
    sub
group by 
    sub.Gender, Rate;
```

I'm trying to do this so I can get a better understanding of how functions work

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by `gender` alone - not by gender and rate :

```
with sub AS
(
   select 
       emp.Gender, emp.VacationHours, pay.Rate
   from 
       HumanResources.Employee emp
   inner join 
       HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory pay on emp.BusinessEntityID = pay.BusinessEntityID
)
select 
    sub.Gender,
    avg(sub.VacationHours) as vac_hours, 
    avg(sub.Rate) as rate
from 
    sub
group by 
    sub.Gender;
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that you are grouping on `rate` which is what you are averaging - don't do that. Also, the common table expression doesn't really fill any function so it can be removed too:

```
select 
    Gender,
    avg(VacationHours) as vac_hours, 
    avg(Rate) as rate
from 
    HumanResources.Employee emp
join
    HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory pay on emp.BusinessEntityID = pay.BusinessEntityID
group by 
    Gender;
```